# Preserve value of textbox using View State in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a button and a textbox. I want a value to be entered in textbox and when I click on button the page will reload but the value should still be in the textbox. How can I do that. The following code doesn't work

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (ViewState["value"] != null)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = ViewState["value"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["value"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewstate can retain the value only till when you are on the same page. You are redirecting to other page. So instead of using viewstate use session.

Answer (score 2):

Response.Redirect does what it says - redirects the request to a NEW page. ViewState won't get applied, ever. If you need a redirection, consider using session instead.

If you don't need a redirection, simply don't redirect and update only parts of the page that need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net webform have already  maintained the viewstate on  page refresh . don't need any code for  handle this operation .

See this : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_aspnetviewstate

referred from : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp

and see this [discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1548944.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ViewState["value"] != null)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = Session["value"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["value"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why would you check for ViewState if you want to take the value from Session anyway? It will probably never pass like this ;) I know, probably just a mistype, but..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are redirecting to a new VIEW so **VIEWSTATE** will not be of any HELP. SO,Use **Session**

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["value"] != null)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = Session["value"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["value"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```